# delete the units from an order from customers based on another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dfs related to the order from customers, and
some steps for preprocessing of that. So, in one df I define some units in the **gramaz df**.
which if we have that in the order, we should delete them. Like, if we have the pepper
in the order, we should change that to:

```
pepper kg--> pepper
```

But, some time I have an order which assigns a number before the units.

```
pepper 100 kg--> pepper
```

So, I want to remove that number exactly before the units. (in the order we have other numbers also, I don't want to delete them, only the number before the units are important and should be deleted).
here is the dfs and here is the output I want.

```
gramaz = pd.DataFrame({'unit':['cc', 'lit','gr', 'kg' ]})
gramaz

    unit
0   cc
1   lit
2   gr
3   kg

order = pd.DataFrame({'order':['100 glass','8 sodium 2 gr', 'br kk cc','mgk 100 lit','red pepper', 'black pepper',  'a 10 kg' ]})

      order
0   100 glass
1   8 sodium 2 gr
2   br kk cc
3   mgk 100 lit
4   red pepper
5   black pepper
6   a 10 kg


the output: 
    
order
0   100 glass
1   8 sodium
2   br kk
3   mgk
4   red pepper
5   black pepper
6   a
```

I tried to use the chatgpt
, I can remove the units, however, I don't know how to remove the numbers!

My dfs are at order 10k rows. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to replace the values, e.g.:

```py
pat = r"\s*(?:\d+\.?\d*\s*)?\b(?:" + "|".join(gramaz["unit"]) + r")\b\s*"
order["new_order"] = order["order"].str.replace(pat, "", regex=True)

print(order)
```

Prints:

```
           order     new_order
0      100 glass     100 glass
1  8 sodium 2 gr      8 sodium
2       br kk cc         br kk
3    mgk 100 lit           mgk
4     red pepper    red pepper
5   black pepper  black pepper
6        a 10 kg             a
```